# Microphone on windows not working for speech_recognition by using python

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I am working on a virtual assistant for desktop in python.
the part of it requires to take input of my voice and give corresponding results.

But for some reasons,it is not taking input of my voice.
it looks like it does not have the permissions to access my microphone. I tried
using  `code F:\programming\development and other\python programming\projects\jarvis for desktop\project.py`(project.py is the name of file i am working with) command in windows power shell which was recommended at https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/live-share/issues/3254

still no results

Code Made so far:

```
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr
import datetime
import wikipedia
engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id)


def wish():
    hour = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)
    if hour >= 5 and hour <= 12:
        speak("Good Morning Mister Abhinav Agrawal")

    elif hour > 12 and hour < 5:
        speak("good Afternoon Mister Abhinav Agrawal")

    else:
        speak("Good evening Mister Abhinav Agrawal")


def speak(str):

    engine.say(str)
    engine.runAndWait()


def takeCommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening...")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        audio = r.listen(source)

    try:
        print("Recognizing...")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')
        print(f"User said: {query}\n")

    except Exception as e:
        # print(e)
        print("Say that again please...")
        return "None"
    return query


if __name__ == "__main__":
    wish()
    leave = False
    while True:
        query = takeCommand().lower()
        if 'quit' in query:
            break
        elif 'wikipedia' in query:
            query = query.replace('wikipedia', "")
            result = wikipedia.summary(query, sentences=2)
            speak(result)
            print(result+"\n")
```

Comment: What happens when you run the code in the terminal? Because that's all VSCode does. Running `code script.py` will just open the file in the editor, not run anything related to your mic.

Comment: for some reason it does not even open my file.instead,it creates several new files of the folder names used in the path and a new python file

Comment: Because you need to put quotes around the filepath since it has spaces

Comment: I just noticed that this fix was suggested for someone who have installed vs code form something named homeberew

Comment: Yes, they are using a Mac, and they are using `live-share` extension, not running Python code

Comment: so is there any fix for window users?

Comment: Please answer the first question - Does your code work when ran directly and not in an IDE?

Comment: when I tried using quotes as suggested,It opened my file in visual studio code and it still does not pick up my voice

Comment: Once again, don't use Vscode. The problem is not VSCode if running even `python "F:\programming\development and other\python programming\projects\jarvis for desktop\project.py"` doesn't work

Comment: this is also not working

Comment: I assume the same happens, when you run any of the examples? https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/tree/master/examples

Comment: i tried some of them and same thing is happening with them

Answer (score 0):

ok so I finally found the solution to this problem
there were two problems:

1. the energy threshold was high and my laptop's inbuilt mic was not able to catch my audio
2. the noise from background was also a problem

fix:
adding `r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)` and adjusitng energy threshold to 150 fixed my problem